# Chrome content script not loading for chrome.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I noticed recently that two of my Chrome extensions weren't working correctly on any of the pages at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps. After some debugging, it seems like the content script is not loaded. Here is a test extension to demonstrate this:

```
// manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

.

```
// content.js
console.log("Loaded");
```

This extension display the text "Loaded" in the console for almost all of the pages I've loaded. This includes http and https pages. But when I go to the chrome store, I don't see this text. What's the reason for this? It might be useful for determining other URLs that won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

Comment: Then try adding this:

`"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }`